# How to verify that a new tab is opened in a browser with TestComplete using C#

Tags: c#, testcomplete

I am testing a website. In the body of website has a URL. After clicking that URL it should be opened in a new tab, not in same window. After clicking the URL link it is opened in new tab browser. I have tested it manually.

I want to verify that feature by using TestComplete with C#Script. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate a click to this link and then check whether the URL of the current page object has been changed and whether a new page object with the target URL has appeared.

```
function Test1()
{
  var browser = Sys.Browser("firefox");
  var numOfTabs = browser.FindAllChildren("ObjectType", "Page").toArray().length;
  var page = browser.ToUrl("http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_target");

  var pageUrl = page.Url; 
  frame = page.Panel(0).Panel(1).Panel(0).Panel(1).Frame("iframeResult");
  frame.Link(0).Click();

  if (page.Url != pageUrl)
    Log.Error("The page's URL has been changed!");

  if (browser.FindAllChildren("ObjectType", "Page").toArray().length == numOfTabs)
    Log.Error("A new tab has not been opened!");
}
```